# How to get parent data if child data does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the child data if it exists but when it is nil it will get the parent data.

I don't want to hard code this in the view's because this would require something like:

```rb
if @product.parent
  @product.price ? @product.price : @product.parent.price
end
```

So I thought it would be better to put something in the product model to override that specific attribute like:

```
# app/models/product.rb
def price
  if self.parent
    self.price ? self.price : self.parent.price
  end
end
```

But the way above would be ver redundant because i would have to do that for every attribute that model has which would be a lot of functions.

Is there any way to make a function that is going to do the same functionality that would apply to all attributes?

I want to be able to get any attribute from the parent if it is not available from the child

Thanks

Comment: You could use a view helper `def price(model) ; model.price || model.parent.try(:price) ; end`

Comment: that is still reduntant because you would have to put each atribute there like price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a function that looks for the attribute in the object first, if not present, it looks for the attribute in the parent object associatated

```
  def get_attribute(attr)
    self.send(attr).present? ? self.send(attr) : self.parent.send(attr)
  end
```

then in the object, you can fetch the attribute using

```
obj = Model.find(id)
obj.get_attribute(:attr_name)
```